# Tensorboard Time Scale and Data Interval Issues

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard, openai-gym

I'm currently playing with the OpenAI baselines and OpenAI Gym environments to get my head around some RL things. I want to visualize the results in Tensorboard, but am having issues with how the rewards are collected. I try to download as a CSV, but the timestep intervals are very arbitrary. Is there a way to set a definite timestep interval to retrieve reward data?

It may be worth adding that I simply want timescale by reward data...if there is a way to retrieve this outside of using Tensorboard, I am certainly open to it.

Comment: can you show an example of your data?

Comment: do you mean the exported csv? @KevinHe

Comment: yeah maybe you can sort them by timestamp then they make sense.

Comment: [here](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/1/9/61282d6c277d1e736720608715722eff-full.png) is a link to a screencap of the CSV exported by Tensorboard...the "wall time" column has equally arbitrary jumps that correspond to (time) step